# Openmp-C++ efficiency: an array of structures vs. several arrays

Tags: c, arrays, structure, openmp, performance

I am using c++ with openmp, and have a concern on the computational efficiency of the following two ways in organizing the data:

(1)

```
struct A
{ 
    int n;
    double v;
    double f[3];
    ....
};

struct A A_array[1000];
```

vs.

(2)

```
int n[1000];
double v[1000];
double f[3][1000];
......
```

and if option (2) is better, which for-loop is potentially faster?

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
      { ......}
```

vs.

```
for (j=0;j<1000;j++)
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      { ......}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you are using the data inside the different variations. Separate arrays means that if you are ONLY using the `f[3]` part of the `struct`, you get no "pollution" in the cache, which is more efficient. On the other hand, if you are loading in `n`, `v` and `f[3]` every time, then you

By the way, I think you'd prefer `double f[1000][3];` over `f[3][1000];`, unless you really use data of `f[x][y]`, where `y` is changing more frequently than `x`. Since each element in `f` is far apart [8000 bytes apart], changing `x` often in this case would cause serious locality jumping for the memory controller & cache, which certainly won't be effective.

In nearly all questions about performance, the DETAILS are highly important, and you can have *almost* identical data, that you do *almost* the same thing with, and just some small change to the algorithm or usage pattern will have BIG impact on the performance. Always, always, benchmark (and make sure you enable reasonable level of optimization, performance benchmarking code that is compiled in debug mode is completely and utterly flawed, since for small pieces of code, the difference can be 10x in speed).